# Access array returned by a function in php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using a template engine that inserts code in my site where I want it.

I wrote a function to test for something which is quite easy:

```
myfunction() { return '($this->data["a"]["b"] ? true : false)'; }
```

The problem is, $this->data is private, and I can't access it everywhere, so I have to use getData(); which causes my problem.

```
$this->getData()['a']['b']
```

does not work, and assigning the value first doesn't either because it will be used directly in an if() block.

Any ideas?

Comment: Assigning the return value definitely does work and is the only way. 

Can you show us your non-working code?

Comment: Well it does not work because the code will be inserted in an if(/*code here*/). So I can't just assign the data before.

Comment: What on earth are you building anyway? :) something with eval?

Comment: What are you trying to check? Do you try to see if the array element exists and has a non-empty value? You can use the function 'empty' for this. This question needs more clarity!

Comment: How is (was) that string value that you return in `myfunction()` processed further? That part is missing in your question.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Since PHP 5.4 it's possible to do exactly that:

```
getSomeArray()[2]
```

Reference: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-62

On PHP 5.3 or earlier, you'll need to use a temporary variable.

Comment: I've got `PHP 5.4.11-1~precise+1` and this feature doesn't work! Got message in response `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`

Comment: +Eugene did you get it working? Maybe others experience the same problem.

Comment: It took till php 5.4 to support array notation returned from functions?! 
What a nasty bug.

Comment: And then you try to get the first element of an array generated by array_filter and start crying

Answer (score 19):

You cannot use something like this :

```
$this->getData()['a']['b']
```

ie, array-access syntax is not possible directly on a function-call.

Youy have to use some **temporary variable**, like this :

```
$tmp = $this->getData();
$tmp['a']['b']    // use $tmp, now
```

In your case, this probably means using something like this :

```
function myfunction() {
  $tmp = $this->getData();
  return ($tmp['a']['b'] ? true : false);
}
```

You have to :

- first, call your `getData()` method, and store its return value in a temporary varibale
- then, use that temporary variable for your test

You don't have much choice about that, actually...

Comment: Well, as I said, my problem is that this code gets inserted, directly in if(/* code goes here */) so defining a function there is not really possible...

Comment: Can you not assign the result of the method call to a variable before the if statement, and use that variable in the if statement, instead of directly trying to call the method from the if statement ?

Comment: Unfortunately no... This is a templating engine, and I have no control over it.

Answer (score 12):

Ok... apparently there really isn't a better way, so I'm going to answer myself with a not so beautiful solution:

I created the function:

```
arrayGet($array, $index) { return $array[$index]; }
```

And used it like this:

```
myfunction() { return '(arrayGet(arrayGet($this, "a"), "b") ? true : false)' }
```

This is not pretty but works.

Answer (score 1):

**`$this`**`->data` is *always* accessible, if it is protected. **`$object`**`->data` is not accessible from everywhere, so if you're returning `$this` in your code, and it is evaluated as such, it should be ok.

Btw, there is a bug in your code: The quotes need to be escaped.

```
myfunction() { return '($this->data[\'a\'][\'b\'] ? true : false)'; }
```

Comment: Yeah sorry... I corrected my post: $this->data is private of course.
Also corrected my typo when creating the bug.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible from PHP version 5.4.

**If you don't want a temporary variable** for that **and your PHP version is less, than 5.4**, than you still can use a few built in functions to get the first or the last element:

```
$x     = 'first?last';
$first = array_shift(explode('?', $x));
$last  = end(explode('?', $x));
$last2 = array_pop(explode('?', $x));
```

**Edit:**
!!! Please note, that in later versions( 5.4+ ) PHP will throw a notice, because end only expects variables as parameter.