# return last numeric key (NOT value) of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array[0] = "hello0"
array[1] = "hello1"
array[2] = "hello2"
```

Now I want to get the last key '2' of the array. I cant use end() because that will return the value 'hello2'.

What function should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the keys are not continuous (i.e. if you had keys 1, 5, 7, for example):

```
$highest_key = rsort(array_keys($myarray))[0];
```

If they are continuous, just use `count($myarray)-1`.

Comment: Hey, since when is the function(args)[key] syntax allowed?

Comment: Also, I think you mean to use array_reverse() instead of rsort(), no?

Comment: No, I meant rsort(). `array_keys()` may not always return the keys in sorted order.`

Comment: For people who want answer to Alix Axel's question: Since PHP 5.4 as answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php

Answer (score 8):

end() not only returns the value of the last element but also sets the internal pointer to the last element. And [key()](http://docs.php.net/key) returns the key of the element this internal pointer currently ...err... points to.

```
$a = array(1=>'a', 5=>'b', 99=>'d');
end($a);
echo key($a);
```

prints `99`

Answer (score 0):

```
count($array) - 1
```

Won't work if you've added non-numeric keys or non-sequential keys.