# Alternative to temporary variable to access array-result from function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742764/php-syntax-for-dereferencing-function-result)

If a PHP function returns an array, the following syntax will not work:

```
$firstValue = $object->methodThatReturnsArray()[0]; // syntax error, unexpected '['
```

This, however, works fine:

```
$temporaryArray = $object->methodThatReturnsArray(); 
$firstValue = $temporaryArray[0]; // temporary will never be reused
```

What is the best syntax to solve this problem, or is creating that variable the recommended approach?

Comment: -1 This has been asked many, many times here. If you want the key `0`, you can use `list($firstValue) = $object->methodThatReturnsArray();`.

Comment: @Artefacto: ok, sorry - not so easy to find.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php/1459393#1459393

Comment: @tucuxi: It's very easy. Look to your right for a whole host of duplicates. The same list appeared as you wrote your question.

Comment: @Tomak: not strictly true, since the list is built from questions and answers, and I only had a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable is the best approach.

Still PHP 5.4 adds the feature to be able using the first mentioned syntax.

Comment: See http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-06-28-1 change titled "Array dereferencing support". More about this change can be read in http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html.

Comment: @yes123 http://www.php.net/releases/NEWS_5_4_0_alpha1.txt - General improvements: Added array dereferencing support

Comment: thanks - will accept after a few minutes. Frustrating because it is common syntax in many C-like languages. @yes123: feature is announced for 5.4, just checked.

Comment: oh god. they are getting ready for php 6: `Changed default value of "default_charset" php.ini option from ISO-8859-1 to
  UTF-8`

Comment: do you know when something like this will be accepted? https://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call `new Object()->method();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can have `list` to the left of the `=` (`list($firstValue) = $object->methodThatReturnsArray();`), if you need anything too deep in the array, a temporary variable is your only option.