# Why can't I index the mysql returned array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access array returned by a function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php)

The code:

```
$cnt = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"))[0]
```

Is giving the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   index.php on line 117

Same for:

```
$cnt = (mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")))[0]
```

This code:

```
$cnt = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"));
$cnt = $cnt[0];
```

is working fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: That's a PHP syntax limitation. Only PHP 5.4 will allow that.

Comment: @bfavaretto, Is there anything I can read about it? Are there other things like this?

Comment: I couldn't find much, but check this: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Comment: You could use either `$cnt = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")),0)` or `$cnt = current(mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't just a problem with `mysql_query`--rather, it's an idiosyncracy in the way that PHP <5.4 handles bracket notation. The following [will fail](http://codepad.org/h2CU9dYK), as well:

```
function get_array() {
  return array('foo', 'bar');
}

echo get_array()[0];
```

But, as you observed, setting the result before attempting to retrieve an element [works fine](http://codepad.org/cL6ZGe95):

```
$arr = get_array();
echo $arr[0];
```

Comment: That's annoying -.- Is there a reason for it?

Comment: That's the million-dollar question for an awful lot of PHPisms :^)

Comment: @Walkerneo No, not really. As already mentioned by bfavaretto, it's been fixed in 5.4. PHP has many oddities like this.

Comment: [Array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Comment: @Walkerneo I suppose you have to continue to dig if you want more info, but [the reason](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html) claims to be that this patch was rejected for a long time because "due to uncertainties about memory issues, as we don't like memory leaks."