# PHP equivalent to JavaScript function()['index']

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access array returned by a function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php)

Trivial question; is it possible to get the current index of a returning array from a PHP function, like JavaScript can like this:

```
function returnSomething()
{
    return ['one', 'two', 'three'];
}

var two = returnSomething()[1]; // two
```

I've always wondered if PHP can do this, I've tried ages ago (but it is invalid to do so), and never got to ask here.

Comment: @Jon Yup, I couldn't find it around here, I didn't know how to explain what it's called, but now I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP can do this [starting from 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php); it's called [array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html).