# Do I have to foreach to access this value?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access array returned by a function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php)

I have a function in a class which returns an array of data for a single item.

```
public function retrieveItemData($item_id) {

    $stmt   = parent::query("SELECT title FROM `item_main` WHERE `item_id` = $item_id");

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
        $item = array(
            'id' => $item_id,
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'url' => $item_id . '/' .$this->generate_seo_link( $row['title'], '-')
        );
    endwhile;

    return $item;
}
```

elsewhere in the class i call the function like so

```
$this->return .= '<td>' . $this->retrieveItemData($rep['source']) . '</td>';
```

`$this->retrieveItemData($rep['source'])` is obviously printing 'Array', how can i access the title key from here?

I have tried

```
$this->retrieveItemData($rep['source'])['title']
```

And

```
$this->retrieveItemData($rep['source'])->title
```

But with no luck.

Comment: try to print_r, that way you can analyze the array better

Comment: My best guess without seeing the parent::query() function would be that fetch is returning a set of rows. Try `$this->retrieveItemData($rep['source'])[0]['title']`. Raygo is right. print_r will give you a good insight here.

Comment: i get syntax error, unexpected '[' if i do that @tommarshall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$item_data = $this->retrieveItemData($rep['source']);

$item_data['title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Array-access syntax on a function call: `$this->retrieveItemData($rep['source'])['title']` is not possible until PHP 5.4.

In earlier versions, you have to use a temporary variable like in Trevor's answer. So you'd want to change the code where you call your function to:

```
$item_data = $this->retrieveItemData($rep['source']);
$this->return .= '<td>' . $item_data['title'] . '</td>';
```