# CakePHP error in Linux

Tags: cakephp

I developed an application in CakePHP - Windows.

Then I put it in Ubuntu and made the necessary settings. Everything works except the line:

```
$this-> set (
    'projeto_id', 
    $this-> requestAction (
        "/Projects/getprojectsofcategory", 
        array (
            'setor_id' => $this->Registration-> read()['Registration']['setor_id'] 
        )
    )
);
```

gives me the following error:

> Fatal Error Error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

and I do not understand why. If I comment out the line gives the following error because it is of the same genre.

Can someone explain me why this error?

Comment: You have an older version of PHP in Ubuntu that doesn't support accessing array elements directly from the method return value. Why space between `$ this`? I didn't know that was even valid.

Comment: i'm sorry. doesnt exist any space between $ this :)

Comment: It's generally best to show the *actual* code you have when asking questions.

Comment: so, should i install the latest version of php?
I'm not going to try now, I do not know what version of php that is installed, but I think it will be the latest :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to upgrade to a newer version of PHP, or you'll have to change your functions.

Check the most voted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php). `$this->Registration->read()['Registration']` is not posible for PHP < 5.4

If you can not upgrade php, you'll need to have an intermediary variable

```
$valueRead = this->Registration->read();

$this-> set (
'projeto_id', 
$this-> requestAction (
    "/Projects/getprojectsofcategory", 
    array (
        'setor_id' => $valueRed['Registration']['setor_id'] 
    )
)
);
```