# Cakephp throws an error unless array is devided

Tags: php, cakephp

So i have an Api call where i get a json array:

When i do the following:

```
$data = $this->HasOffers->get_full_detail_report()['data']['data'];
$this->set('data',$data);
```

i get an error saying `an internal error has occoured`

However if i do:

```
$data = $this->HasOffers->get_full_detail_report();
$data2 = $data['data']['data'];
$this->set('data',$data2);
```

everything is working correctly.

Now my question is why is this happening? and how can i fix it?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? IIRC, the `function()['key']` syntax is only valid in PHP >= 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using in the first example is only available in PHP >= 5.4. See relevant section of PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88

You can see an example running in different versions of PHP at: http://3v4l.org/XhCKH

Your CakePHP site likely has error reporting turned off so, rather than displaying the syntax error, it is displaying an Internal Error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you have debug < 2, so the description of the error is not very detailed. However, that behaviour is known to be a PHP < 5.4 issue ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php) regarding that subject).

To "fix" it, you need to upgrade PHP to 5.4 at least. Or, just use an intermediary variable for those cases, it's not *that* bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the array you are referencing in the first example only exists after the function `get_full_detail_report()` is called.  PHP does not like this.  PHP wants your array to exists before you reference it.  I assume that it attempts to locate any variables within your statement before performing any operations, which would mean it is searching for an array that does not exist until it performs those operations.

If anyone has any more insight into this, I would welcome their revisions / comments.