# CakePHP application displays Syntax error, unexpected [

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, amazon-ec2, syntax-error

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected '[' 
Line: 10
```

I'm running my cakephp app on a linux server ubuntu 3.7, it's cakephp 2.3.7 and PHP 5.3.1.
Now, I'm running WAMP on EC2 after installing linux. On my localmachine I run XAMPP on Windows  7, and it does not get the same error. This is the code where it displays error:

```
 10:  <?php foreach ($this->Session->read('Customer')['Addresses'] as $key => $value) {
 11:  $ids[$z++] = $value['id'];
 12:  ?>
...
```

Since it does not give any error on localmachine, I'm assuming it's got something to do with the server environment. Please help, Thankyou! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with your PHP version. PHP < 5.4 doesn't accept things as `somefunction()['array']`.

The solution would be to separate that function like

```
$customer = $this->Session->read('Customer');
foreach ($customer['Addresses'] as $key => $value) {
   //etc
```

The problem is documented and you can find [another questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469032/cakephp-throws-an-error-unless-array-is-devided/18469382#18469382) regarding that around.

(PD: of course, other solution is to upgrade PHP to 5.4 at least, but you'll need to keep in mind the [migration changes](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php))

Comment: At my shared server I needed to update from PHP 5.4 to  5.5 fortunately it had an option in cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Only PHP 5.4+ supports "Function array dereferencing":

http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

You have to assign the result to a variable first to work on older versions:

```
$cust = $this->Session->read('Customer');
foreach ($cust['Addresses']...
```