# Turn off notices in cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, notice

I am new with cakePHP. I facing issue with notice on live server. I want to suppress or turn off these notices. I have tried adding,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

in the *index.php* file in main folder. Also added same in *bootstrap.php* file but no luck. Can anybody suggest me how I can do this.

Comment: Make sure it's `Configure::write('debug', 0)` in core.php file.

Comment: @Rikesh Yes, debug is set 0 still getting the notices. Code stopped working when notice is shown. Version of cakePHP is 2.3.7.

Comment: Please check your php version on live and on staging server , i think there is PHP version issue . please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623774/cakephp-application-displays-syntax-error-unexpected

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the debug feature by turning debug to 0 in the app\Config\core.php file

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

If still you get the same issue so please check your live server Php version and also check the  same on development server, I think there is php version compatibility issue so please see
link http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/markstory/2013/07/05/cakephp_2_3_7_2_4_0-beta_released

Hope it should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

In the core.php file in /app/config, find this line and edit the level of errors you want to show:
`Configure::write('Error', array(
        'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
        'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
        'trace' => true
    ));`

You may now add or remove the error levels as given on this page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: For CakePHP v3.6 you have to use `'errorLevel' => E_ALL ^ E_USER_DEPRECATED,`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting warnings and notice just because your DEBUG is TRUE. to solve this probem.

Go to `config/app.php`  and just change true to false as done below..

Find this line

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

And change above line to

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', false), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

Comment: Alternatively, just set the `DEBUG=false` in the `.env` file

Answer (score 1):

Open config/core.php

- 0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
  *
- Development Mode:
- 1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
- 2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.

seach this

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `config/app.php` file:

```
'Error' => [
        'errorLevel' => E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING,
        ......
        ......
],
```