# Assign number as array key name

Tags: php, arrays

I need to assign in an associative array a number as key name, but if I do:

```
// Places (generated by mysql)
$places = array (
    0 => '1234',
    1 => '2345'
 );

// Week stats (generated by mysql)
$week = array (
  1234 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'iid' => '1234',
      'mid' => 'xxxxxxxx',
      'name' => 'Name1',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'iid' => '1234',
      'mid' => 'xxxxxxxx',
      'name' => 'Name3',
    )
  ),
  2345 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'iid' => '2345',
      'mid' => 'xxxxxxxx',
      'name' => 'Name2',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'iid' => '2345',
      'mid' => 'xxxxxxxx',
      'name' => 'Name4',
    )
   )
  );

  foreach($places as &$place) {

     echo $place;

     $i = 0;

     foreach($week[$i] as &$value) {

       echo $value["name"];
       $i++;
     }

  }
```

it doesn't work:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/Y1g37t

because seems I should call it with:

```
echo $arr[<specific index>];
```

Instead I need to set "1234" and "2345" as strings, like this array:

```
$arr = Array("foo" => "bar");
```

So I can call it with

```
$arr[0] // bar
```

How can I do?

### Solution

Thanks to @kirilloid

i use this code:

```
$vararr = array_keys($week);
$key =  $vararr[$i];
```

To get the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may either use [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
echo $arr[array_keys($arr)[0]];
```

or [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) and [current](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```
reset($arr);
echo current($arr);
```

Comment: I like the first solution but doesn't works :( 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[''

Comment: I needed to split it in two lines and now works! perfect, exactly what I needed!

Comment: Hmm, actualy first solution [works in php 5.4+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php). And I get used to javascript, where this always were possible.

Comment: I know, in JS I use it too, but in my machine with PHP I need to split it as I said.

Answer (score 3):

It because it's an map and map associates values to keys so you have to do this :

```
<?php
$myNumber = 1234;
$myValue = "foo";
$arr = Array( $myNumber => $myValue );
echo $arr[1234];
?>
```

And don't forget to replace the ":" at your first line !

To iterate on a "map" you can use the foreach function :

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```

This should display your key and the value associated :

```
1234
foo
```

Here is the difference with a simple array:

```
$array = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world");
echo $array[0];
```

Comment: ok but what if I need to iterate it in a for loop? I need to assign numbers as key names and not as index, like they was trings...

Comment: You iterate over the whole array... like `foreach($arr as $k=>$v){ .. echo $k; }`. Instead of `$k[0]`, it would just be `$k` inside the loop

Comment: the ":" was a typo on stack, by the way I was using 'as &$value' but even using your suggestion I get '$key = 0'

Comment: @user2070518 if this is the only code you have i don't see where is your problem. My code works well on my computer :s

Comment: sorry I was not clear, I iterate a 2nd array and I use $i as index incrementing it each time by 1, then I use $i as key value in the 1st array. I guess this is the misunderstanding

Comment: Also, regarding your comment "by the way I was using 'as &$value'"... Why are you passing by reference? Are you modifying the array in any way?

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem here - this is how it is supposed to work.

If you create an array like this:

```
$myNumber = 1234;
$myValue = "foo";
$arr = Array( $myNumber => $myValue );
```

then the index of the element is `1234`, not `0`.

You can retrieve it with `echo $arr[1234]`

If you need to loop over the array you can do so with

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
  // do something with $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. As the value of $myNumber is 1234, you should access the array element like this:

```
echo $arr[1234];
```

If you need to access them in a foor loop you can get the keys as an array:

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
$keys_count = count($keys);
for ($i=0; i<$keys_count; $i++) {
    echo $arr[$keys[$i]];
}
```

Comment: yes but I need to call it using 0,1,2,3 ($i) etc in some for loop, so I can't use $myNumber

Comment: @user2070518: `foreach($arr as $key => $value) ...`

Comment: I've edited my answer so you can loop the values by using 0, 1, 2, etc. Anyway I'm curious about why you can't iterate as suggested.