# "Same" syntax, different results using mysqli fetch_assoc()?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, this is not a problem than need solving, but rather a question out of curiosity and want of clarification. A was struggling with a piece of php/mysqli and while debugging and splitting the code up I discovered that my code was working, just not the way I wrote it.

**Initial code (Not working)**

```
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT nick FROM userdata WHERE id=".$_SESSION['uid']);
// ... error checking here ...
for($i = $result -> num_rows - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    $result -> data_seek($i);
    $nick = ($result -> fetch_assoc())['nick']; // crash
}
```

**Final code (Working)**

```
$result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT nick FROM userdata WHERE id=".$_SESSION['uid']);
// ... error checking here ...
for($i = $result -> num_rows - 1; $i >= 0; $i--){
    $result -> data_seek($i);
    $row = $result -> fetch_assoc(); // working
    $nick = $row['nick']; // working
}
```

So, can anyone enlighten me as to why the first code simply breaks for me?

Best regards.

Comment: PHP's compiler can't handle the syntax in the first case, except in recent versions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP 5.4 (2012-03-01) and later versions support array dereferencing from a function call.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.
>
> As of PHP 5.5 it is possible to array dereference an array literal.

Then it shows examples.  See *Example #7* on that page.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. Will mark it as answered as soon as I can.