# Why is PHP throwing this parse error?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, php-parse-error

I have a small question for you all. I currently have my site on 000webhost, and the following line:

```
$price  = explode(".",$item->sellingStatus->currentPrice)[0];
```

causes the following error:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /home/a1257018/public_html/scripts/myfile.php on line 58

When it doesn't cause this on localhost. The code should work... explode returns an array and `[0]` simply calls the first item. Why is this throwing an error?

Comment: Which PHP version is installed locally?

Comment: are you sure the result of 'explode()' is an array and the array is not empty?

Comment: @Zim84 Even if it was not, that would not cause a syntax error

Answer (score 10):

This syntax is only allowed in PHP 5.4+. You have to use temporary variables in older versions:

```
$tmp = explode('.', $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice);
$price  = $tmp[0];
```

Has been [discussed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/).

Comment: Gah.. that's what I was afraid of. I believe 000webhost uses PHP 5.2. Looks like I have a lot of editing to do. Thanks!

Comment: Oh the joy of php ;-) http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Comment: I still don't know why nobody implemented this earlier.

Comment: Blaming PHP design for this isn't really correct, it's just kicking PHP for the sake of it.... all languages add new features with new versions, using new features of languages like Ruby, Java or C# or any other language against an older version of that language will give errors

Comment: I don't blame PHP. I just say I don't understand their decision. And I hope Java and C# (not sure about Ruby) implemented array access of return values in their childhood.

Answer (score 1):

Use it as

```
$array  = explode(".", $item->sellingStatus->currentPrice);
$price = $array[0];
```

It's because your server doesn't support this syntax because of `php < 5.4`, here is the [same error](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ky9F1X) showing in `5.3.19` and [working here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/W6ilh7) using `php-5.4`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$price  = explode(".",$item->sellingStatus->currentPrice);
$currentPrice = $price[0];
```

This should work.