# PHP use function with return as an array

Tags: php

Let's suppose I have a function that returns an array. Let's name it `arrFunc()`.
Now, if I need a quick use of this function (eg. return first/second/... value of the array), can I write something like this `arrFunc()[0]` to return first array value? Or, is there something similar?

This is just a personal curiosity...

Comment: `arrFunc()[0]` works in PHP 5.4+.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Does it work even with associative arrays? Like `arrFunc()["test"]`.

Comment: If you have an idea of how to do something, you should really try it first, before asking if it works.

Comment: This would have been really easy to test yourself. If you had tried on a pre-5.4 version, got an error, and were looking for an alternative, that would be a valid question. But it seems you haven't done so, so this is just plain lazy.

Comment: Meanwhile, here is a site where you can test the same PHP code in multiple versions: http://3v4l.org/

Comment: @Xriuk: Yeah, it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access array returned by a function in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can :

```
function arr()
{
    return array(1, 2, 3, 4);
}

echo arr()[0];
```

give this result:

```
1
```

Pay attention that it's only true for PHP 5.4+ !

Comment: Yeap. If he don't specify his version, I assume that he have the last one.

Comment: @EmrysMyrooin If you can add more explanation, it would be better for some people who want to learn