# alternative to operator[] for arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any alternative to operator[] for arrays in php?

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
$e = getArray()[1];
```

In my php version this doesn't work. Any suggestons of graceful syntax?

At the moment the two-line solution seems to be the only possibility:

```
$arr = getArray();
$e = arr[1];
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you give us your PHP version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Just change it to be a two-liner:

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
$e = getArray();
echo $e[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it like this:

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

$e = getArray();
echo $e[1];
```

It will have a consistent behavior across all PHP versions.