# Accessing GET variable using Laravel's Input class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm given a GET variable by a script that is this:

`input[0][value]`

How can I access this value using Laravel's Input class?

I've tried `Input::get('input[0][value]')` and it returns nothing.

Comment: Yes.  If it was just ?input=input, I'd get it by `Input::get('input')`  When I do the same thing due to the brackets it's not working properly.  Not a beginner.

Comment: And it's `beginner` not `begginer`

Comment: Try array dereferencing then; as in `Input::get('input')[0]["value"]`. It's likely to just mirror the input array structure.

Comment: Tried this as well, `syntax error unexpected [`

Comment: Needs PHP 5.4 of course; else use a temporary variable.

Comment: What do you mean temporary variable?  Can't use 5.4 unfortunately due to other software on the machine requiring 5.3.

Comment: [Access array returned by a function in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1459377)