# What is it called when you access an array element of the return value of a function?

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic

Some languages support using `getArray()[0]` instead of `arr=getArray();arr[0]`. What is this called?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, this doesn't have a special name in c++. Might be a stupid question (im only familiar with c++ like languages), but what programming languages don't support it?

Comment: PHP doesn't support it. I remember reading an article about how Javascript supports this and there was a special name for it.

Comment: PHP does support it now: [example](https://ideone.com/xIv5Gw). [The answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php) suggests it became valid in PHP 5.4

Comment: Oops, I'm so used to not using it in PHP, so I never bothered checking to see if I can use it now. I guess it can be called something like "array-accessible function return value."

Comment: Yes, I remember being quite pleased when it became available. That and being able to use `[]` instead of `Array()` for an array literal.

Answer (score 0):

Things like `getArray()[0]` work as a result of the language's grammar (and semantics) permitting arbitrary expressions (which compute an array) to have array accesses appended onto them.

Java calls the relevant portion of the grammar an [array access expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13).

```
ArrayAccess:
    ExpressionName [ Expression ]
    PrimaryNoNewArray [ Expression ]
```

(If you're wondering about the `PrimaryNoNewArray` rule, the NoNewArray part is there because multidimensional array creation in Java looks like `new int[10][5]`. You don't want that second `[ ]` to be confused with an array access.)

In C99, it's part of the `postfix-expression` rule:

```
 postfix-expression:
     ...
     postfix-expression "[" expression "]"
     ...
```

If the grammar doesn't allow arbitrary expressions to the left of the `[`, then you end up in the situation that (apparently?) PHP was in.