# Search array by keys and return values

Tags: php, arrays

**Array**:

```
$cities = array("Paris" => "10", "Amsterdam" => '20', "California" => '30', "Barcelona" => "70");
```

**Sort**:

```
asort($cities);
```

**print_r**:

```
print_r (array_keys($cities));
```

**Results**:

```
Array ( [0] => Paris [1] => Amsterdam [2] => California [3] => Barcelona )
```

I want to return the city who has the key 2. (It should be **California**)

**UPDATE**

I solved it like this (Thanks to ArSeN):

```
$array1 = array_keys($cities);
$city = $array1[2];
```

Comment: `var_dump($array[2])`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to know which city has the key 2? Or do you mean you want to know which key in the array has the value "California"?

Comment: @ArSeN Yes. Because I have already the key (Ranking) and I want to now which user has this key.

Comment: Then the response from u_mulder is already what you are looking for. Just access the array entry with the specified key like this: `$array[2]`. If you feel that this helped you, you should probably close the question, as this is very basic understanding of how arrays work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$city = array_keys($array1)[2];
```

Stores "California" in $city.

Comment: IIRC older PHP versions don't support it like this. You might want to store the result of array_keys in a variable first and get your index afterwards. $tmp = array_keys($array1); $city = $tmp[2];

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10482105/2979155) - it's supported since version 5.4