# Access array keys returned by a function without an variable

Tags: php, configuration, ini

I have created a function in that style:

```
execQuery("SELECT id FROM contadeusuario WHERE session='$sessao'")['numRows']
```

I always use this syntax, but in the latest projects, when I upload them to production, it doesn't work.

`execQuery(string $query)` returns an array with `['status']`, `['result']` e `['numRows']`, in the other servers I have to attribute the value to a variable.

```
$NR = execQuery("SELECT id FROM contadeusuario WHERE session='$sessao'");
```

and then use

```
$NR['numRows']
```

How can I configure my server so it always work like in the first way? I have looked for an option in the .ini files and forums, but didn't find anything

Comment: Questions in portuguese should be asked in [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of: [Access array returned by a function in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-62), array dereferencing is available only on PHP 5.4 and above. ([See the new features for PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration54.new-features.php))

> ```
> <?php
> function getArray() {
>     return array(1, 2, 3);
> }
>
> // on PHP 5.4
> $secondElement = getArray()[1];
>
> // previously
> $tmp = getArray();
> $secondElement = $tmp[1];
>
> // or
> list(, $secondElement) = getArray();
> ?>
> ```

Your production server uses a PHP version inferior to 5.4, so you should either upgrade it or stick to temporary variables.