# What does it mean by: $this->get_soap_provider_options()['location']

Tags: php, soap

I found a PHP library in which a line is:

```
$this->get_soap_provider_options()['location'];
```

But this is producing error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...path to file.. at line...
```

I could not understand why `['location']` is written after function argument `get_soap_provider_options()`. It should be `get_soap_provider_options('location')` or `get_soap_provider_options(array('location'))` or something like this.

I think this line of code is for PHP 5.4 or higher. How can I write this line for an older version of PHP?

Comment: `get_soap_provider_options()` returns an array and you try to access a value (within the array) through the key `location`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing, example 7.

Comment: Tom, how to write the $this->get_soap_provider_options()['location'] line for older version (before 5.4)? Because after closing argument braces, it is not allowed to write `['location']` in older version of php. It should be something like this: `$this->get_soap_provider_options('location')` or `$this->get_soap_provider_options(array('location'))` ....... how to write?

Comment: Try to store the result from the function in a variable and access the value through the variable.

Comment: I could not understand why ['location'] is written after function agrument get_soap_provider_options(). It should be get_soap_provider_options('location') or get_soap_provider_options(array('location')) or something like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access array returned by a function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459377/access-array-returned-by-a-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

What you stated about it being for **PHP >= 5.4** is correct. This syntax is used to access an array returned by a function. This is called [array dereferencing](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-62) (from a function or method).

To access the value from the array in **PHP < 5.4** you'll have to store the result from the function or method in a variable. This variable will act as a "temporary" variable (see *example 7* on the documentation):

```
$tmp = $this->get_soap_provider_options();
// now you can use > $tmp['location']; <
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```